# How can one partially disable a mousebutton in javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, html5-canvas

I would need to disable the right click of the mouse inside my p5js canvas so it wont bring up the little properties window but the right click on its own can still be used as an eventlistener key.
How does one achieve such thing?

example: (from dropbox)

[image]

Thanks.

Comment: What means partially disable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can intercept it easy with jQuery and call `e.preventDefault()`.

```js
var c = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.arc(95,50,40,0,2*Math.PI);
ctx.stroke();

$("#myCanvas").on("contextmenu",function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  // show your custom context menu here or what ever
  console.log("event: right-click on canvas triggered");
})
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.js"></script>
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="200" height="100" style="border:1px solid #d3d3d3;">
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by adding an event listener for contextmenu:

```
  document.addEventListener( "contextmenu", function(e) {
    console.log('right click!');
    e.preventDefault();
  });
```

The console.log piece is just to illustrate that it is working. You could build your own function to create a nice context menu.

The e.preventDefault() is what prevents the default context menu to load.

---

```js
document.addEventListener( "contextmenu", function(e) {
    console.log('right click!');
    e.preventDefault();
  });
```

```html
Right click here!
```

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

```js
    if (document.addEventListener) { // IE >= 9; other browsers
        document.addEventListener('contextmenu', function(e) {
            alert("You've tried to open context menu"); //here you draw your own menu
            e.preventDefault();
        }, false);
    } else { // IE < 9
        document.attachEvent('oncontextmenu', function() {
            alert("You've tried to open context menu");
            window.event.returnValue = false;
        });
    }
```

```html
<body>
Lorem ipsum...
</body>
```